# Does cactus destroy XP orbs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a trap using cactus in 1.12 for zombie pigmen in the nether, but I am not sure if the cactus is destroying XP orbs. I get a lot of XP but I was expecting more.

[image: my trap setup]

Its working perfectly for killing them, i dont need their drops , just the xp

Answer (score 9):

"Experience orbs can be destroyed by fire, lava, explosions and cacti"
from the wiki https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience

Also mobs will not drop xp unless you hit them at least once 5 seconds before they die.

Comment: Since 1.8, any hostile zombie pigman drops XP, even if it was aggroed by another pigman being hit by a player.

Answer (score -1):

If mobs are not killed by hand, they generally drop less, usually nothing. If you want an XP farm, you must find a way to kill a lot of mobs easily by hand.

Hint: fall damage is your friend. For every block fallen beyond the first 3, the entity looses 1 health. Pigmen have 20 health. So if a pigman falls 22 blocks, it has 1 health (1/2 heart) left.

Also important: mobs always spawn at minimum 25 blocks away from the player.

Comment: This is good information, but doesn't directly answer the question. You may want to consider addressing the OP's question "Are XP orbs destroyed by cactus" by editing your answer.